# C++ Primer 5th Edition Exercise 1.23 Question about the Solution I Found

Tags: c++

The exercise: Write a program that reads several transactions and counts how many transactions occur for each ISBN.

The answer I found on Github:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "include/Sales_item.h"

int main()
{
    Sales_item currItem, valItem;
    if (std::cin >> currItem)
    {
        int cnt = 1;
        while (std::cin >> valItem)
        {
            if (valItem.isbn() == currItem.isbn())
            {
                ++cnt;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << currItem << " occurs " << cnt << " times " << std::endl;
                currItem = valItem;
                cnt = 1;
            }
        }
        std::cout << currItem << " occurs "<< cnt << " times " << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For example if the input ISBN is like this:

```
A A B A B C
```

The output would be:

```
A occurs 2 times
B occurs 1 times
A occurs 1 times
B occurs 1 times
C occurs 1 times
```

Which isn't quiet right because they're not properly grouped. The excercise didn't specify that records for each ISBN should be grouped together. (Though it's specified in the next exercise.)

I haven't found a right solution online yet. I've been thinking about this excercise for a while and still don't have much clue on how to solve it.

I've only learned about while, for, if so far. This seemingly easy exercise is kind of a challenge for me. Hope you guys can give me, a beginner some clue about it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This only counts sequential equality. To group by ISBN you need some way of associating a count to an ISBN.

Comment: I think the intention is that _when you test the program_, i.e. in _the input_, ISBNs are supposed to be grouped together. This is in the introductory chapter where you haven't learned the necessary tools to solve the variation you mention in the question yet. In other words the excercise doens't intend for you to solve it for input `A A B A B C`, but only `A A A B B C`.

Comment: Side note: Don't just look for answers online. Also use the [Mk 1 Noodle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_brain).

Comment: To solve the problem the way you interpreted it, you need at least chapter 3 ("Strings, Vectors and Arrays"), but better yet also chapter 11 ("Associative Containers"). I suggest you come back to this problem once you made it through these chapters and try to implement it with these tools according to your interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

use a `std::map<char, int> chcounts;` where the key is the character.

You can then do

```
  chcounts[ch]++;
```

this takes advantage of the fact that if you reference a map element using [] and the entry does not exist it will get created and default initialized

or if you have strings do

```
 std::map<std::string, int> counts;

 ....
 counts[isbn]++;
```

Comment: The key is a class type `Sales_item` as indicated by the member function `.isbn()`. It probably has a `operator>>` to allow it to be read a string or char. But they will likely need to add `operator<` to make this solution work.